# Array Key Value in ASP .NET with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, key

I am new to asp.net with C#. Now I need a solution for one issue.

In PHP I can create an array like this:

```
$arr[] = array('product_id' => 12, 'process_id' => 23, 'note' => 'This is Note');

//Example
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 12
            [process_id] => 23
            [note] => This is Note
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [process_id] => 19
            [note] => Hello
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 8
            [process_id] => 17
            [note] => How to Solve this Issue
        )

)
```

I want to create the same array structure in asp.net with C#.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` for quick lookups of a value (your object) based on a key (your string).

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dictionary.Add("product_id", 12);
// etc.

object productId = dictionary["product_id"];
```

To simplify the `Add` operation, you could use collection initialization syntax such as

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "product_id", 12 }, { "process_id", 23 }, /* etc */ };
```

---

**Edit**

With your update, I would go ahead and define a proper type to encapsulate your data

```
class Foo
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; } 
}
```

And then create an array or list of that type.

```
var list = new List<Foo>
           {
                new Foo { ProductId = 1, ProcessId = 2, Note = "Hello" },
                new Foo { ProductId = 3, ProcessId = 4, Note = "World" },
                /* etc */
           };
```

And then you have a list of strongly-typed objects you can iterate over, bind to controls, etc.

```
var firstFoo = list[0];
someLabel.Text = firstFoo.ProductId.ToString();
anotherLabel.Text = firstFoo.Note;
```

Comment: Thanks for your Quick Reply,

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 12
            [process_id] => 23
            [note] => This is Note
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [process_id] => 19
            [note] => Hello
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 8
            [process_id] => 17
            [note] => How to Solve this Issue
        )

)

I want to do like this...

Comment: If you want to do that, I would simply define a class to encapsulate your data and just have an array or list of instances of that class. Jon's answer suggests perhaps an anonymous type, which is also an option.

Comment: sure sir, it would be a great help to me.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a mapping from `string` to `object`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "product_id", 12 },
    { "process_id", 23 },
    { "note", "This is Note" }
};
```

Alternatively, perhaps you'd like an anonymous class, if this is just a way of passing data around:

```
var values = new {
    ProductId = 12,
    ProcessId = 23,
    Note = "This is Note"
};
```

It really depends on what you're trying to achieve - the bigger picture.

EDIT: If you've got the same "keys" for multiple values, I would probably create a specific type for this - it's not clear what sort of entity this is meant to represent, but you should create a class to model it, and add appropriate behaviour to it as required.

Comment: Thanks to give a Quick Reply, I modified the question, please have a look sir. Actually i am storing the product_id, process_id, note into array for every form post. Finally i will manipulate the array and store into database.

Comment: @user707852: That doesn't really change my answer - you could apply my answer to either case. To be honest though, I suspect you'd be better off creating a type to encapsulate these values...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>[] map = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>[10];

map[0] = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>();
map[0].Add("product_id", 12);
map[0].Add("process_id", 23);
map[0].Add("note", "This is Note");

map[1] = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>();
map[1].Add("product_id", 5);
map[1].Add("process_id", 19);
map[1].Add("note", "Hello");
```

Comment: I think `List<T>` makes more sense than an array here.

Comment: Oups yeah with the edited question, same structure, it would make alot more sense too use the above answer and it is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Associative array could be represented in C# using Dictionary.
Its Enumerator.Current would return a keyValuePair.

So your array would like

```
var associativeArray = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ {"product_id", "12"}, {"process_id"," 23", {"note","This is Note"}};
```