# Multidimensional array with two values for a single key

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create an array which can have two values for a single key.
I want to get the array formatted like this:

```
array = 
{
    "key" => {"value1", "value2"}
}
```

I have tried formatting the array like this:

```
public string[,,] array = new string[,,] 
    {
        {
            { "1", "5", "6" }, 
            { "2", "5", "7" }
        },

        {
            { "3", "1", "2" }, 
            { "4", "1", "3" }
        }
    };
```

But I only get 16 values to loop through, and I would like to access them from a key I put.

How can I create the array in a way so that I can get the desired output?

Comment: Arrays don't have keys. Are you looking for a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) or a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2) implementation?

Comment: Hmm, so it is different then PHP...
What is more simmiliar to PHP array, or in this case, what is easier to implement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Key Value in ASP .NET with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970506/array-key-value-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp)

Comment: You could be looking for C# MultiMap, or Maybe just a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`

Comment: I don't know PHP but I found you this question (the duplication candidate). Check it and if it answers your question, accept it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do, is use a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) with a string *key* and a [Value Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8) for the value. Dictionaries have a fast *key* lookup by nature, and *Named Value Tuples* gives you some sanity when accessing the key

```
// Instantiated the dictionary
var funky = new Dictionary<string,(int Value1, int Value2)>();

// add some values
funky.Add("mykey",(1,5));
funky.Add("anotherKey",(4,5));

// access the values
Console.WriteLine(funky["mykey"].Value1);
Console.WriteLine(funky["anotherKey"].Value2);
```

Comment: @Mr. King, this is the answer you should accept and learn from it!

Comment: Omg thx!
I have actually made this before I saw your comment: 

    string[,] arr = new string[,]
            {
                { "1", "2" },
                { "3", "4" }

            };
            Dictionary<string, object> list = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length/2; i++)
            {
                string[,] ari = new string[,] { { arr[i, 0], arr[i, 1] } };
                list.Add(i.ToString(), ari);
            }

But your soution is much more elegant!

Ill accept it as an answer, thx man! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking for array. You are probably searching for dictionary. So, MS says this about dictionary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8

**Represents a collection of keys and values.**

So, you need to access some values with given key. This is it. 
Example:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> xs = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
            {
                {"key1", new string[] {"value1","value1.1"} },
                {"key2", new string[] {"value2","value2.2"} },
            };

xs["key3"] = new string[] { "test42" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it, is create a dictionary where you can access the value with a unique key, and the value can be any type you want.
In this case it is Dictionary with a string key and List of strings value

```
var keyValues = new Dictinary<string, List<string>>();
keyValues.Add("key1", new List()
    {
        "Value1",
        "Value2"
    });
```